Avalonia Compilation error when Binding is used
I am pretty new at Avalonia and trying to display a text box property value changed when a button is clicked thru binding
using INotifyPropertyChanged.
I have this code in my View/MainWindow.axaml:
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="3" Margin="4" Width="200" Spacing="10">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextBlockName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
              </StackPanel>

The error message I get:
MainWindow.axaml(52,56): Error AVLN:0004 Avalonia: Cannot parse a compiled binding without an explicit x:DataType directive to give a starting data type for bindings. Line 52, position 56
TextBlockName property belongs to MainViewModel class:
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace DPConfig.ViewModels;
using System.ComponentModel;

using ImageExample.Helpers;

public partial class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
#pragma warning disable CA1822 // Mark members as static
    public string Greeting => "Welcome to Avalonia!";
    //public Bitmap? ImageFromBinding { get; } = ImageHelper.LoadFromResource(new Uri("avares://LoadingImages/Assets/8QtmykRt_400x400.bmp"));
 
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private string _textBlockName= "Test";
    public string TextBlockName
    {
        get => _textBlockName  ; 
        set
        {
            _textBlockName = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    
    private void Button_OnClick()
    {
        TextBlockName = "Clicked";
    }
    
#pragma warning restore CA1822 // Mark members as static
}

I get similar error when I bind Button_OnClick event for the button as well.
Tried using  <TextBlock Text="{Binding #MainViewModel.TextBlockName}" but that throws an error as well and it throws this error message:
MainWindow.axaml(57,30): Error AVLN:0004 Avalonia: Unable to find element 'MainViewModel' in the current namescope.
Added "using DPConfig.ViewModels;" in MainWindow.axaml.cs but to no avail. Any idea?
Update:
When I first created  the project from Avalonia templates, it came with a MainView.axaml which I suppose used for control. That one has the following content:
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DPConfig.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"
             x:Class="DPConfig.Views.MainView"
             x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel">   <======
  <Design.DataContext>
    <!-- This only sets the DataContext for the previewer in an IDE,
         to set the actual DataContext for runtime, set the DataContext property in code (look at App.axaml.cs) -->
    <vm:MainViewModel />
  </Design.DataContext>

  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
  
</UserControl>

This code compiles but when I add the namespace
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DPConfig.ViewModels"
followed by x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel"> in MainWindow.axaml file, the compiler complains about it. Puzzled.

Have a look at https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/basics/data/data-binding/compiled-bindings and check whether you enabled compiled bindings, whether your code works without compiled bindings (ReflectionBinding) and whether you comply with the requirements when using compiled bindings.

Thanks , yes compiled binding is enabled (by default) in the project file. I think my main problem is a missing reference to MainViewModel namespace in  MainWindow.axaml file (to use the data context properly) . I saw an example in AvaloniaUI.Quickguides repo, where they add this namespace by using the following syntax:  x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
But if I do this, I get a compilation error saying:
MainWindow.axaml(8,9): Error AVLN:0004 Avalonia: Unable to resolve type namespace alias vm Line 8, position 9.
This must have changed since this was using dotnet v 6 and I am on 8.2

In the linked documentation the xmlns definition looks a bit different: xmlns:vm="using:MyApp.ViewModels" (notice the using instead of clr-namespace)

However, I don't really know which you should use, only that some people have situations where one works and the other one does not

Thanks, I got it to work yesterday by using ObservableProperty from CommunityToolkit, I had to use the modified property name that the convention allows, not what I called my property. Weird but it worked out in the end, and  my goal was to use ObservableProperty anyway (INotifyPropertyChanged was just for trying out)
